# Set audio level of mp3

Tags: python-3.x

I need to make program, that amplify or reduce audio files volume so they have same maximal decibels. And I have no clue how to do that in python. Please, help. Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial or code-writing service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), as well as [ask]. Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 0):

Use pygame's mixer. Pygame is not a standard library so use `pip install pygame` in commandprompt/terminal and all. Here is the code:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('Your_Audio.mp3')
mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
mixer.music.play()

while True:
    print("'up' to raise the volume")
    print("'down' to lower the volume")
    query = input(" ")

    if query == 'up':
        mixer.music.set_volume(0.9)

    if query == 'down':
        mixer.music.set_volume(0.1)
```

Here I have preset the value but you could just keep it as a variable like

```
sound_volume = 0.5

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('C:/Users/Ramesh/Pandu/Python/tgfcoder-FrozenJam-SeamlessLoop.flac')
mixer.music.set_volume(sound_volume)
mixer.music.play()

while True:
    print("'up' to raise the volume")
    print("'down' to lower the volume")
    query = input(" ")

    if query == 'up':
        sound_volume += 1
        mixer.music.set_volume(sound_volume)

    if query == 'down':
        sound_volume -= 1
        mixer.music.set_volume(sound_volume)
```

Comment: If you want a maximum decibel kinda thing just add in the if functions `if sound_volume > maximum_decibel:` `sound_volume = maximum_decibel` make sure you set it as a variable.